# knit HTML to cat function

Tags: r

I use the cat function in my file, but when I do Knit to HTML file it print what I put in the cat with ##,
for example if it is the code:

```
cat("the plot repsent..")
```

It will look like this in the HTML
[image]

Is it possible to print the string without ## (with a cut or other function),
I want it to be in the HTML  file like that:
[image]

Thanks in advance to the assistants!

Comment: typically, your code chunk needs the option `\`\`\`{r, results='asis'}`, but this will apply to all the output in the chunk, and from your question it's not clear if that will solve the problem

Comment: it solved the problem! Thank you very much for your help